# Modify Node Value C# with ID

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, linq-to-xml, xelement

Here is my XML :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <Selection>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Nom>Name 1</Nom>
    <DateReference>0</DateReference>
    <PrefixeMedia>Department</PrefixeMedia>
    <FormatExport>1630</FormatExport>
    <TraceAuto>Oui</TraceAuto>
    <SubID></SubID>
  </Selection>
  <Selection>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Nom>Name 1</Nom>
    <DateReference>0</DateReference>
    <PrefixeMedia>Department</PrefixeMedia>
    <FormatExport>1630</FormatExport>
    <TraceAuto>1</TraceAuto>
    <SubID>1</SubID>
  </Selection>
```

My problem is I would like to modify for example the node content of `<Nom>Name 1</Nom>` which is located in `<Selection></Selection>` which have `<ID>1</ID>` (Search by ID)

I'm using XElement and XDocument to do simple search but I need some help to solve this problem above. (Developpment on SilverLight

Best Regards.

Comment: Take a look at this: Answer is accurate i assume, as it was John Skeet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482986/how-to-update-a-xml-node NOTE/TLDR: you cannot update a single node in XML, you're going to have to load the file, change that node in-program, and then rewrite the XML file.

Comment: What exactly is the problem: (1) finding the correct `<Nom>` node to update, (2) changing the value of the node or (3) persisting the change to wherever you got the XML from (file, database, ..)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know how to get at the correct `<Nom>` node to update, the trick is to first select a `<Selection>` node that *contains* the correct `<ID>` node, *then* you can get that `<Nom>` node.

Something like:

```
XElement tree = <your XML>;
XElement selection = tree.Descendants("Selection")
      .Where(n => n.Descendants("ID").First().Value == "1") // search for <ID>1</ID>
      .FirstOrDefault();
if (selection != null)
{
  XElement nom = selection.Descendants("Nom").First();
  nom.Value = "Name one";
}
```

Note 1: By using `Descendants("ID").First()` I expect every Selection node to contain an ID node.
Note 2: And every Selection node contains a Nom node
Note 3: Now you still have to store the whole XML, if that's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is using `XmlDocument`:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(@"\path\to\file.xml");

// Select the <nom> node under the <Selection> node which has <ID> of '1'
XmlNode name = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Selection[ID='1']/Nom");

// Modify the value of the node
name.InnerText = "New Name 1";

// Save the XML document 
xmlDoc.Save(@"\path\to\file.xml");
```